# User select:none causes input field to be inaccessible on Safari

Tags: html, css

With these css styles I prevent the highlighted text selection on a page.  But this causes the input fields to be locked from user input on Safari.

```
* {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none; // locks fields on Safari
-khtml-user-select: none; // locks fields on Safari
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;      
}
```

Is there a way on Safari to prevent user selection without interfering with input fields?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why not just apply the style to everything but the inputs?

css3 way:
`*:not(input){...}`

Comment: Don't forget the textareas: `*:not(input textarea){...}`

Comment: @tomaspolach your syntax is incorrect.  The correct syntax is: *:not(input):not(textarea)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing new :)

```
*:not(input, textarea){
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none; // locks fields on Safari
    -khtml-user-select: none; // locks fields on Safari
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For every cases in css:

```
*:not(input), *:focus:not(input) {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline-style:none;/*IE*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something a little more precise.

```
input[type=text] 
{
  -webkit-user-select: text;
}

input[type=password]
{
  -webkit-user-select: all;
}
```

Comment: whats the difference in terms of functionality?
sorry i know i can try it, just really busy...

Comment: This will only select the specific input elements with the type attribute set to text or password. This is required for older browsers that don't support `not`. However, I would do this: `* { ... user-select: none; } input { ... user-select: text; }`