# Text input in iOS webview not working after second tap

Tags: javascript, html, ios, input, webview

We are having a bug in our iOS app when using an HTML text input in a webview.

Here is the HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If the input is tapped once, it works perfectly : it gets the focus and the keyboard appears, the user can type. However if the user taps again on the input, the cursor moves to the far left of the input and nothing that is typed appears in the input.

This bug can be seen on iOS7 and iOS8 devices in a webview. It does not appear in Safari or Chrome.

To see this behavior, I've uploaded [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEpMbr1YWUA).

I have tried to find a JS solution, playing with `.focus()`, without any success. Does anyone have a clue on where it might come from, or how to solve this?

Comment: can you add your webview code?

Comment: I have many applications using webview and they are working fine. If you can test on fly try to add this metatag in html head section:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />

Comment: try to add this also to previous meta tag:
user-scalable=no

Comment: @blex I tried your code and it's working fine for me (iPhone5 iOS 8.1), are you doing any other process or this is the only HTML that you are loading in your WebView?

Comment: Found a workaround, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278930/ipad-is-not-writing-text-in-the-input/34731858#34731858

Answer (score 0):

Add this metatag in html head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it's not solving the issue. Maybe it is app-related...

Comment: Even if that did not solve my problem, I am awarding you the bounty instead of letting it go to waste for the time you took looking for an answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you :-) , hope to help you in another situation. Regards