# Cannot type into textarea with fastclick on iOS 9

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, fastclick

I've spent the last few days search for a solution, but everything that should work (according to the documentation) does not.

I'm using [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to eliminate the 300ms delay for HTML5 application intended to run on an iPad.  Everything works great, except I lost the ability to type text into textarea.  Simple one-line fields work, but not the multi-line textarea.

When I tap on the text area, the keyboard pops up and I can start typing.  The first letter typed appears in the text area - but that's all.  Subsequent letters do not.  If I close the keyboard and tap on the text area again, I can type another one letter in.

I've tried everything suggested, including `needsclick`, `needsfocus`, etc.  I tried to edit the fastclick.js to extend the special code for handling `input` elments to also cover `textarea` - nothing.

I'm at a point where I may have to dump fastclick just because of it and do everything manually myself, as I already lost almost a week on this problem.  Yet, before I go that way, maybe somebody can point me in the right direction.

Note, the problem is present on iPad and iPhone with iOS 9.2 (specifically, 9.2.1 - the latest version).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the reason turned out to be rather simple - and nothing to do with fastclick.  It was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566606/717214) that actually solved it for me.

In my CSS, I had the following:

```
body * {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

body input {
    -webkit-touch-callout: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

This was done to deal with silly users that would "touchstart" on a button then start thinking about what they want - and before "touchend", ios would then go into the copy/paste mode.

It was then explicitly disabled on inputs to allow copy/paste within the text.  Yet, I forgot to include textarea in the second part. Now the second piece looks like this:

```
body input, body textarea {
    -webkit-touch-callout: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

And everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery fix,

```
$('input.form-control,textarea').on('click',function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```

This worked in my case.

Comment: This worked for me because the parent element had a mousedown event that was preventing the cursor from going into the textarea.  So instead of having to remove the mousedown, adding this allowed me to keep both functionalities.