# Disable copy and paste from input fields in Webview in a phone gap/cordova based ios app.

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I have a phone gap/cordova application. I have a view that has a link, 2 textfields and text.

> I want to remove copy,paste and select option from the web view.

Using:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];
```

I was able to disable copy paste and select menu from web view, but it still lingers in the input fields , i.e textfields.

What i tried was to **disable long press on the webview** , that disable the magnify glass and as a result disables copy and paste menu, but the menu occurs while we double tap on the textfield too. How can i disable both long press and double taps on the webview?

I am bit confused whether my app will clear the review process for app store if i disable the magnify glass.

Please help me get a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

I think this has been discussed elsewhere but what ended up working for me was adding the following to the css.

```
/******************
disable select touch and hold and highlight colors
******************/
html {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

and if you still want it to work for input then
I added

```
input {
    -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: default !important;
}
```

Thanks to [Phonegap styles -webkit-user-select: none; disabling text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812587/phonegap-styles-webkit-user-select-none-disabling-text-field)

Comment: thanks Leo...this works but not for any input area. This works only on links or texts. When i tap and hold on the input area , i still get the copy and paste menu.

Comment: hmmm  I think I had the opposite problem and had to add it back in for inputs let me check

Comment: You are right I get the same behaviour. Sorry Thats all I got. Other than making your own textbox by using a text and listening for keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use this.
 <style type="text/css">
 *:not(input):not(textarea) {
   -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
  }       
 </style>
 If you want Disable only anchor button tag use this.

 a {-webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you want to remove copy & paste functionality: Security concerns? If you want keep text selection and copy & paste within your application BUT you want to prevent people to copy&paste your content to other apps then check out Cordova plugin [cordova-disable-copy-paste](https://github.com/MarcoEidinger/cordova-disable-copy-paste)

Comment: This might answer the question, but link-only answers are discouraged. Links tend to break; and then such answers turn (almost) useless.