# External Sharepoint site's text inputs inaccessible on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, angularjs, sharepoint

I have a form setup in a webpart in our SharePoint solution and am having an issue when testing on Apple devices where the input fields are not accessible/appear to be grayed out.  This application uses ajax server calls to pre-fill form entries and I am using AngularJS for client-side handling.  Why is this only happening on these devices?

example field:

```
<input id="nhaole-vf-address" 
    ng-model="parent.streetAddress" 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    required />
```

[image]

Comment: why do you have an id assigned to the input? e.g. `id="nhaole-vf-address"`

Comment: I'll answer that question if you could provide what relevance it has to mine?

Comment: your input has Id attribute. It might be related, maybe other script included in your bundle mess this input element by using his id

Comment: Jossef - I removed the id tags. Aeolin - I added screen, as you can see the field is grey were it should be accessible.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your CSS? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819565/user-selectnone-causes-input-field-to-be-inaccessible-on-safari

Comment: Try removing the `required` attribute.  SharePoint uses XHTML 1.0 Strict, which doesn't have a reference for `required`.  OR - try changing it to `required="required"`, since XHTML requires that each attribute be assigned a value.  I've been doing a lot of work in SharePoint lately and have come across a few funny quirks like this.  I haven't had this problem specifically, but it's worth a shot :-).

Comment: Which version of sharepoint? 2010, 2013, online? Also are you using safari? what about chrome on apple devices? Same issue?

Comment: oh sorry Aaron, I've tried in chrome and safari on iPhones and iPads

Comment: I think you should put name on your input.
Does the issue only occur on the newest IPhone / IPads (IPhone 6)?
They seem to be very strict on JS, try to reproduce the issue with older IPhone (5, 4) if it doesn't reproduce, you may be looking for a return somewhere in the javascript that is working on older browsers but latest IPhones require it...
Not sure why but we spent 6 days finding out such an issue.

Comment: Do you have any `user-select: none;` styles in your page?

Comment: Is this question still active? Did you try to use [VorlonJs](http://vorlonjs.com/) to debug your web page directly and check what is happening within your page once loaded?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is 5 years old and the OP has not provided enough context to make even the question generally useful to the broader Stack Overflow audience.